# Cannot connect to a server on my PC, Web API

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, post, asp.net-web-api

I've got a problem with a local server running on my PC using OWIN and Web API written in C#. I've made a small app with Phonegap and used with succes the connection with the emulator on my phone. Now I've exported my app to my iPhone, but I cannot seem to POST my string to the server running on the computer.

I've used the IP address from my PC with the designated port, but my Ajax call doesnt come through. Is there something I forget?

```
$.ajax({
        type       : "POST",
        url        : "http://192.168.178.15:9000/api/system",
        //xhrFields  : {withCredentials: true},
        crossDomain: true,
        data       : { '': "buttonOne" },
        dataType   : 'text',
        success    : function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error      : function() {
            console.error("error");
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is response you get when you paste the url "http://192.168.178.15:9000/api/system" on a browser?

Comment: I get a bad request, HTTP error 400 when I try to connect with my browser on the PC where the server is running.. With my mobile phone I cannot seem to make a connection and with my Macbook I also cannot get a connection. If I use localhost:9000 on my host PC I get the connection with the corresponding response. So this means my IP isn't right or something?

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my server. Now I've shut it down and I got a very quick error that there is a problem loading the page. That means previous time I could connect but there was something wrong in the config. Altought I have no idea what I can go on with this information.

EDIT: I've turned off my firewall and now I get a Bad Request - Invalid Hostname on all my devices (iPhone, Macbook) so that is a step further. Now I need to actually get these values  of the server thus without these bad requests..